# Extract WordPress theme after some customization from live hosting. Purpose: for reuse theme

Tags: wordpress, themes

I'm Ibrahim. I'm a student and a freelancer. I make custom WordPress websites as per order.

I always Think to extract themes after customization from the WordPress websites. I do not use my personal computer hosting. I always work on hosting servers because they are fast and easy to access plugins and more easy to demonstrate work.

If some know how I download theme after customization in .zip file for future use from live WordPress hosting.
I am not talking about any other person or website theme. I want my theme, not website backup.
Hope you understand what I am trying to express.

thanks for paying a read my post.

Comment: Just use File Manager and zip theme file in theme folder, Then access that file from browser like this http://example.com/wp-content/themes/name.zip and you can download zip file.

Comment: Or use File Manager WordPress Plugin for zip and extract from WordPress Dashboard.